# fixed menu bootstrap isn't scrolling

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scroll, menu, fixed

I've read the bugs report on github and it's supposedly fixed but I can't get mine to do it.
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12738

I've also compared code with the actually demo
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

I can't figure out why this doesn't work. I am removed all my custom styles and am only just bootstrap 3.3.4

Let me know if you need further information

```
<body>
<header>
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button data-target="#menu" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">BRAND</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="menu" style="height: 1px;">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Home2</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
                        fasdfasdf
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu">
                        <li>asdf</li>
                        <li>asdf</li>
                        <li>asdf</li>
                        <li>asdf</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Report</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
</header>
</body>
```

Comment: do you want it to be fixed or static because your link to bootstrap says navbar-fixed-top but your code is navbar-static-top? please clarify and resubmit. If you want it to be fixed change the code in your nav class to reflect navbar-fixed-top instead on navbar-static-top reload the page and enjoy.

Comment: Are you still having issues? I need feedback to help facilitate resolution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to check your closing tags right now end body tag is still open and so is the header tag

for fixed-navbar:

```
<!-- Fixed Navbar -->
<header>
    <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button data-target="#menu" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">BRAND</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="menu" style="height: 1px;">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home2</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
                            fasdfasdf
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">asdf</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">asdf</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">asdf</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">asdf</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Report</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

For Static Navbar:

```
<!-- Static Navbar -->
<header>
    <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button data-target="#menu" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">BRAND</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="menu" style="height: 1px;">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home2</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
                            fasdfasdf
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">asdf</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">asdf</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">asdf</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">asdf</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Report</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

See [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/blayderunner123/Lm1oo1xa/)